# Still not solving the reactjs sass install proccess

Tags: reactjs

I tried a lot to install the node-sass inside my workpless but it's still not solve and compile error.

```
./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/index.scss)
To import Sass files, you first need to install node-sass.
Run `npm install node-sass` or `yarn add node-sass` inside your workspace.
Require stack:
- F:\React Js\ReactJs Environment\February\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\getDefaultSassImplementation.js
- F:\React Js\ReactJs Environment\February\node_modules\sass-loader\dist\getSassImplementation.js
```

[image]

I try to check the version but it's showing and sass still not working , please help me

Comment: Do you see 'node-sass` in your `package.json` file under the `scripts` key?

Comment: Hello, After the pc switch off and on than it's work fine but withouth pc switch off it's showing error when I install node-sass, what's the problem?

Comment: may be browser save the  cookie, how can I solve without shut down the computer?

Comment: clear browser cache and clear node cache, then try